# Ghostscript.Net error while opening stream

Tags: ghostscript.net

I'm using Ghostscript.Net (v1.2.3) to create images from PDF in my .NETCore (v3.1) web application.

I'm trying to open the stream of the uploaded PDF file like this.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < request.Form.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        var file = request.Form.Files[i];

        using (var rasterizer = new Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer())
        {
             rasterizer.Open(file.OpenReadStream());  //Error here
        }
    }
```

But I get an error on the Open() function:
**An error occured when call to 'gsapi_init_with_args' is made: -15**

Having a closer look, -15 is a **gs_error_rangecheck** and in the ghostscript function [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/base/gsdsrc.c) this error is said to be raised if: "**Returns gs_error_rangecheck if out of bounds.**"

The stream seems to be correct, not empty...

Version of ghostscript installed is 9.52

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Almost certainly the problem is the PDF file, which has something wrong with it. I very much doubt the problem is with the function you are pointing at. Without seeing the PDF file I can't comment further. Note that Ghostscript.NET is not provided by Artifex, it is not part of Ghostscript, it is a separate wrapper.

Comment: I just gave a try with Magick.net, it's working with it. The pdf seems not to be the problem. (And I also tried with other pdf as well)

Comment: Doesn't mean the PDF file is not at fault. If you are convinced the problem is Ghostscript.NET then you should remove the Ghostscript tag.